# I can't connect to socket from the outside

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a simple server/client program pair.
On LAN they work fine, but when i try to connect from the "outside" it says connection refused. I shut down firewalls on both machines but i am still unable to connect, and i double checked the ip.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Jake

Code:

```
import socket 
host = '' 
port = 9888 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port))     
s.listen(1) 
conn, adrr = s.accept() 
conn.send("Hello, world!") 
s.close() 

Client: 
import socket 
host = '68.x.x.x'
port = 9888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket_SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port)) 
print s.recv(200) 
s.close()
```

Comment: Can you show your code, please?

Comment: Have you forwarded the required ports in your router?

Comment: You're sure you're connecting to the machine (e.g. not a router in between)?

Comment: Really belongs on ServerFault - This is a network admin issue.

Comment: @Romain: maybe it is network, but for now he thinks it's his code... might as well isolate the problem before moving

Comment: The code on the server is:

import socket
host = ''
port = 9888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, adrr = s.accept()

conn.send("Hello, world!")
s.close()

Client:

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket_SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
print s.recv(200)
s.close()

Hmm there might be a router, but it is a normal IP (e.g not 192.168.2.xxx)

Comment: Im sorry for the mess, i couldnt find the code tag....

Comment: I updated the post with the code now

Comment: @Jake set host to the same value in client and server. If the server throws an error then the ip you have is your router's and you need to forward ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one of two possible issues.

1. Erroneous network configuration
2. Bug(s) in code

The way to debug this is to try and rule one out. If we can get rid of the Code issue then we know it is a network issue.

Get a Socket Server and client that you know works and then try them as standalone programs. inside and outside of the firewall. 
[Go to this site](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html) and download the examples. Change the ports in both the client and the server, compile and run them. First on same machine within network, second from two machines on same network and then server from within and client from outside of network.

Answer (score 1):

How's the argument you're passing to the `.bind` call for your server socket?  That's the single likeliest cause -- e.g. if you're using `192.168.x.y` for whatever values of `x` and `y`, or `10.x.y.z` likewise, that's a local-network address only, not routed by inter-network routers by internet conventions (most routers can be programmed to forward some incoming packets to a specific local-network address, typically depending on ports, but that's very specific to router's brands and models).

Comment: So basically i have to forward ports?

Comment: @Jake, unless your computer is running with an externally-accessible static IP on a public subnetwork (i.e. **not** 192.168.etc, or 10.etc), yes, port-forwarding from your router (who had _better_ have an externally accessible public IP -- if not static, you can use dyndns or similar services to ameliorate that) is the way to go. See superuser.com for more details, as "how do I best obtain port forwarding on this specific model of router" is not a programming question per se.

Comment: @Jake:  Yes.  It's extremely likely that you are locally using "RFC1918" addresses (that's the IETF standards proposal document which discussions the sets of reserved addresses that are used for isolated networks and which, over the years, have been used when doing NAT (network address translation) on the borders between small and home LANs and the Internet.

It's possible that your ISP may block almost arbitrary lists of ports and types of traffic through their routing infrastructure for various reasons.  This is less common with better ISPs and more common with cable companies, for example.